Getting a const std::type_info& from a std::type_index
Is there a way to convert from a std::type_index to a const std::type_info&?
My understanding is that std::type_index is a wrapper around a const std::type_info* that merely provides operators for std::hash, std::equal_to and std::less so that it can be used to with standard library maps and sets. Are std::type_info objects compiled statically into the program? If so, I feel there should be a way to get a const reference to them from a std::type_index
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index

Which is the underlying problem? It seems to be a XY problem actually...

There is std::type_index::name...

I want to be able to invoke .name() on it or construct a boost::stl_type_index from it so I can invoke .pretty_name() on that.

"My understanding is that std::type_index is a wrapper around a const std::type_info*..." It literally says in the documentation you referenced that type_index class is a wrapper class around a std::type_info object,

unmangling-the-result-of-stdtype-infoname might interest you.

I am more interested in what you would need this for. I usually see people use this to make some runtime decisions made on types, there are better ways for this.  All your examples however (std::hash) are compile time class (or function) templates and the will NOT do anything with typeinfo or typeid.

@PepijnKramer it's for a serialization system that saves a collection of objects of different types into a json file. I've come to the conclusion that the only sensible way to deal with this is to create my own type_index class with a proper name() function

Just use or at least have a look at the nlohman/json library, this is very much a solved problem. What you are missing is that you can use (meta) template programming techniques. The only time I really need typeid/typeinfo is if I want to output a type as a string (debugging).

@PepijnKramerthat library looks nice, I love the support for json literals. Overall it doesn't look as manageable as using boost.describe and boost.json though and I don't see how it solves the problem of serializing type names.

There is no way of getting back a std::type_info from a std::type_index.
If you are in control of the code that is using typeid, then you can replace that with boost::typeindex::type_id or boost::typeindex::type_id_runtime, otherwise you will have to demangle the result of std::type_index::name yourself.
